Explaining Matplotlib Animation Script in Python: Constructing a Sine Wave Curve
Can someone explain this Python code to me?
I'm trying to understand the inner workings of this code, which generates an animated plot using Matplotlib. Here's a breakdown of what each part does:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation 
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch 
import os


desktop_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop")


fig, (axl, axr) = plt.subplots(
    ncols=2,
    sharey=True,
    figsize=(12, 4),
    gridspec_kw=dict(width_ratios=[1, 3], wspace=0.1),
)
axl.set_aspect(1)
axr.set_box_aspect(1 / 3)
axr.yaxis.set_visible(False)
axr.xaxis.set_ticks([0, np.pi, 2 * np.pi], ["0", r"$\pi$", r"$2\pi$"])


theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 50)
axl.plot(np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta), "k", lw=1)
point, = axl.plot(0, 0, "o", color='red')


sine, = axr.plot(theta, np.sin(theta), color='blue')


con = ConnectionPatch(
    (1, 0),
    (0, 0),
    "data",
    "data",
    axesA=axl,
    axesB=axr,
    color="C0",
    ls="dotted",
)
fig.add_artist(con)


def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, i, int(i * 25 / np.pi))
    sine.set_data(x, np.sin(x))
    x, y = np.cos(i), np.sin(i)
    point.set_data([x], [y])
    con.xy1 = x, y
    con.xy2 = i, y
    return point, sine, con


fps = 60
duration = 5  
total_frames = fps * duration

frames = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, total_frames)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig,
    animate,
    frames=frames,
    interval=1000/fps,  
    blit=False,
    repeat=True,
)


output_path = os.path.join(desktop_path, "animation_seno-2.mp4")


Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=fps, metadata=dict(artist='Lenin'), bitrate=1800)
ani.save(output_path, writer=writer)

plt.show()

This script creates two subplots: on the left, it draws a circle with a red point that moves along it; on the right, it plots the sine function. A dotted line connects the two plots. The animation runs for 5 seconds at 60 frames per second (fps), showing the movement of the point and the updating sine curve.
I would appreciate any insights into how each part of this code contributes to the animation's behavior. Thank you!

Most of the code is just setup and admin. The two key parts are this function:
def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, i, int(i * 25 / np.pi))
    sine.set_data(x, np.sin(x))
    x, y = np.cos(i), np.sin(i)
    point.set_data([x], [y])
    con.xy1 = x, y
    con.xy2 = i, y
    return point, sine, con

... which is called by this method:
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig,
    animate,
    frames=frames,
    interval=1000/fps,  
    blit=False,
    repeat=True,
)

If you stepped through the code you'll find that it sits between these two. FuncAnimation() repetitively calls animate(i) and provides the value for the input i.
point.set_data(...) is responsible for updating the left graph,
sine.set_data(...) updates the right,
con is the line joining the two.
i would be better named to theta, as that is what it is representing in the animate(i) function.
